# File increasing in size after deleting content

Tags: php

I recently cleaned up some .PHP files of mine with alot of code that was not needed so I deleted those lines, in one case it was around 200 lines of code.

The strange thing that occured is, after re-saving that one .PHP file, the size went from 70,3 kb to 72,5 kb.

How is that possible ?

Comment: it's not? Seems very unlikely filesize goes up after removing lines. Perhaps the meta information is updated as well?

Comment: File was originally created with Notepad++ and also edited with Notepad++

Answer (score 4):

a) there are less lines but they are longer.

b) your editor auto-magically changed your indentation and replaced say, 2 spaces with 4 or a tab char with 4 spaces.

c) your OS is lying to you

d) your eyes are playing tricks

e) some kind of char-encoding juggling voodoo going on

Answer (score 0):

A few invisible things can make a file apparently bigger, so best guesses include

- original had \n line endings, new one has \r\n
- original had lots of latin1 chars >127, new one uses UTF-8
- original used tabs, new one uses spaces